# Why can the web browser render fonts like Open Sans that are not installed on my system?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

Relating the mechanism which permit a browser to display correctly a text formatted wiht a certain Font-Family, it should be described in this way:

the font-family property lets designers specify a prioritized list of fonts for the browser to use to display content. If the preferred font is not installed on the user's computer, the browser will attempt to use the second font in the list. If the user does not have of the preferred fonts installed, a default font is used to display the content.

In Windows 7 the set of fonts installed on the user's computer font should be viewed in Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Fonts.

Now in my installed fonts "Open sans" is not listed, and yet my IE11 are able to correctly reproduce a text formatted in "Open sans".

Where is the repository where IE11 get the "Open sans" font?

Thank you very much

Comment: Open Sans is provided by Google as a webfont, https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans, and is referenced on a website like this: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. So the actual font file is hosted by Google.

Comment: Go and put it into the answer box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [`@font-face`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#at-font-face-rule):

> The `@font-face` rule allows for linking to fonts that are
>   automatically fetched and activated when needed. This allows authors
>   to select a font that closely matches the design goals for a given
>   page rather than limiting the font choice to a set of fonts available
>   on a given platform.